How many states is it possible to query back from head state using the Beacon API?
How far back from head state is it possible to query Beacon state using Beacon API JSON RPC endpoints?
The consensus clients section of the Ethereum developer docs points us to the Eth Beacon Node API. The API has a debug/state/ endpoint where the input "Can be one of: "head" (canonical head in node's view), "genesis", "finalized", "justified", , <hex encoded stateRoot with 0x prefix>."
I want to look up historical states by slot number. How far back from head state does this work?

you need to run archival mode, as state is saved only every 2048 slots, fyi: https://docs.prylabs.network/docs/advanced/beacon_node_api
